# sugarcrm version 6 community search by email?

Tags: sugarcrm

trying to add the possibility to search by email on sugarcrm 6 community version. I have changed searchform2.php to allow that 
but when I search it returns no results. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to add an entry like this to the modules//metadata/SearchFields.php $searchFields array...

```
'email'=> array(
        'query_type' => 'default',
        'operator' => 'subquery',
        'subquery' => 'SELECT eabr.bean_id FROM email_addr_bean_rel eabr JOIN email_addresses ea ON (ea.id = eabr.email_address_id) WHERE eabr.deleted=0 AND ea.email_address LIKE',
        'db_field' => array(
            'id',
        ),
        'vname' =>'LBL_ANY_EMAIL',
    ),
```

Then add the 'email' field to the modules//metadata/listviewdefs.php file array and you should be good to go.